# Define Equality of Lists Function

Tags: idris

Type-Driven Development with Idris presents this exercise:

```
same_cons : {xs : List a} -> {ys : List a} -> xs = ys -> x :: xs = x :: ys
```

However, I attempted to implement it via:

```
data EqList : (xs : List a) -> (ys : List a) -> Type where
   Same : (xs: List a) -> EqList xs xs

sameS : (xs : List a) -> (ys : List a) -> (x: a) -> (eq : EqList xs ys) -> EqList (x :: xs) (x :: ys)
sameS xs xs x (Same xs) = Same (x :: xs)

same_cons : {xs : List a} -> {ys : List a} -> (eq : EqList xs ys) -> EqList (x :: xs) (x :: ys)
same_cons {xs} {ys} eq = sameS xs ys _ eq
```

I inferred the `x` in `EqList (x :: xs) (x :: ys)` because I'm confused how to get an `x` if `xs` and `ys` are empty.

Also, the above compiles, but it failed when I tried to call it:

```
*Exercises> same_cons (Same [1,2,3])
(input):Can't infer argument x to same_cons
```

Answer (score 2):

The implicit argument `x` cannot be inferred in your use case because there is no information in the call `same_cons (Same [1,2,3])` to constrain it to anything. If you fix the type of the result, that will give you the choice of `x`, e.g.

```
λΠ> the (EqList [0,1,2,3] [0,1,2,3]) (same_cons (Same [1,2,3]))
Same [0, 1, 2, 3] : EqList [0, 1, 2, 3] [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

since the choice of `[0,1,2,3]` for `x:xs` unifies `x` with `0`.

BTW you can simplify the definition of `same_cons` since the `eq` argument's type determines `xs` and `ys` so you can let Idris infer it:

```
same_cons : (eq : EqList xs ys) -> EqList (x :: xs) (x :: ys)
same_cons eq = sameS _ _ _ eq
```

Answer (score 2):

To clarify on how to get the `x`:
Everything in lowercase in the type decleration will become an implicit argument, if it isn't already explicit. So

```
same_cons : {xs : List a} -> {ys : List a} ->
            (eq : EqList xs ys) -> EqList (x :: xs) (x :: ys)
```

is the same as

```
same_cons : {a : Type} -> {x : a} -> {xs : List a} -> {ys : List a} -> 
            (eq : EqList xs ys) -> EqList (x :: xs) (x :: ys)
```

That's where the `x` is hiding. So you could use `{x}` on the left hand side of the definition to get it. Or just let Idris handle all the stuff and use Cactus' definition. For future problems with arguments, you can use `:set showimplicits` in the REPL to show you all the implicit arguments when asking for types, e.g. `:t same_cons`.

And when Idris cannot infer the value for an implicit argument, you can help it by giving the resulting type like Cactus did or set the implicit argument to a value:

```
*> same_cons {x=0} (Same [3,2,5])
Same [0, 3, 2, 5] : EqList [0, 3, 2, 5] [0, 3, 2, 5]
```