# List Equality w/ `cong`

Tags: equality, idris, referential-transparency

Following my other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37063005/define-equality-of-lists-function/37074682#37074682), I tried to implement the actual exercise in [Type-Driven Development with Idris](https://www.manning.com/books/type-driven-development-with-idris) for `same_cons` to prove that, given two equal lists, prepending the same element to each list results in two equal lists.

Example:

`prove that 1 :: [1,2,3] == 1 :: [1,2,3]`

So I came up with the following code that compiles:

```
sameS : {xs : List a} -> {ys : List a} -> (x: a) -> xs = ys -> x :: xs = x :: ys
sameS {xs} {ys} x prf = cong prf

same_cons : {xs : List a} -> {ys : List a} -> xs = ys -> x :: xs = x :: ys
same_cons prf = sameS _ prf
```

I can call it via:

```
> same_cons {x=5} {xs = [1,2,3]} {ys = [1,2,3]} Refl
Refl : [5, 1, 2, 3] = [5, 1, 2, 3]
```

Regarding the `cong` function, my understanding is that it takes a proof, i.e. `a = b`, but I don't understand its second argument: `f a`.

```
> :t cong
cong : (a = b) -> f a = f b
```

Please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two values `u : c` and `v : c`, and a function `f : c -> d`, then if you know that `u = v`, it has to follow that `f u = f v`, following simply from referential transparency.

`cong` is the proof of the above statement.

In this particular use case, you are setting (via unification) `c` and `d` to `List a`, `u` to `xs`, `v` to `ys`, and `f` to `(:) x`, since you want to prove that `xs = ys -> (:) x xs = (:) x ys`.